# What is the bitcoind command to send all coins to another address?

Tags: bitcoind

I'm running bitcoind and I want to send all my coins to another address. What is the command for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Bitcoin Core 24.0.0 you can use the [`sendall`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/24.0.0/rpc/wallet/sendall/) RPC:

E.g.

```
bitcoin-cli -named sendall recipients='["<bitcoinaddress>"]' fee_rate=<sat/vB>
```

Note that `sendall` will spend all of your UTXOs by default, including UTXOs that cannot pay for their own input weight. If you would like to maximize the funds received to the recipient address by not spending uneconomical UTXOs, use the `send_max` option.

```
bitcoin-cli -named sendall recipients='["<bitcoinaddress>"]' fee_rate=<sat/vB> send_max=true
```

RPC Documentation here: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/24.0.0/rpc/wallet/sendall/

Answer (score 27):

To be strict, OP asked to send **all** coins, which @michael.schuett didn't answer.

The key thing to do this is the last optional bool argument of the `sendtoaddress` RPC command called `subtractfeefromamount`. The way to use it is:

```
bitcoin-cli walletpassphrase <passphrase> <timeoutInSeconds>
bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress <bitcoinaddress> `bitcoin-cli getbalance` "" "" true
```

Answer (score 5):

This command:

`sendtoaddress <bitcoinaddress> <amount>`

will do the trick.

Look at the bitcoind api for more info: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list